# Read certain information from a file relating to datetime chosen in DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a file that has weather information that I am reading and placing into a structure then I am adding it to a list. I have a dateTimePicker control that the user will use to select a date in the month of January and when they do that, I need it to print to the listBox control the date and the weather information of that day that I have stored in the list. I have already tokenized the file and put into the structure variables and added it to a list.

When I pick a date through the dateTimePicker control, I end up getting all of the dates and information at once. I believe because I don't understand how to use the dateTimePicker control, that I can't figure this out.

So, when I pick January 1, 2018, I need it to bring in the listBox just that days date and the weather information such as precipitation, high temp, low temp. I hope I have explained everything clearly enough for you to understand.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Chapter9_Problem1_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // create new structure
        struct Weather
        {
            public string date;
            public string precipitation;
            public string highTemp;
            public string lowTemp;
        }
        // create new list
        private List<Weather> weatherList = new List<Weather>();

        // method to get info from file and store into list 
        private void fileData()
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            inputFile = File.OpenText("weather.txt");

            while(!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                // create instance of the weather structure
                Weather weather = new Weather();
                // read the file and store into info variable
                string info = inputFile.ReadLine();
                // create char array for delimiter
                char[] delimiter = { ';' };
                // split info by each delimiter
                string[] tokens = info.Split(delimiter);

                // store the values into the structure weather variables
                weather.date = tokens[0];
                weather.precipitation = tokens[1];
                weather.highTemp = tokens[2];
                weather.lowTemp = tokens[3];
                // add to the list
                weatherList.Add(weather);
                    
                
            }
            
        }
       

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // dateTimePicker method
        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call file data method
            fileData();

            // create datetime object
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
            // assign datetime object to the datetimepicker control
            dateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            foreach(Weather weather in weatherList)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(weather.date + weather.date + weather.highTemp + weather.lowTemp);
            }
            

        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI Paragraphs are allowed here :)

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that you're actually making use of the datepicker's value. Sure you assign it to a variable (`dateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;`) , but you don't actually use it for anything.

Comment: My suggestion: parse the dates from the file to a `DateTime` in the `Weather` model. Once you've done that you can filter `weatherList` based on `weather.date.Date == dateTime.Date`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm struggling with. I can't quite figure out how to when the user selects a certain date, that it prints to the listbox the correct date from my list

Comment: Is the date in the file always in the same format for every line? Can you provide a sample of the date from the file?

Comment: It has to be in a list that I get the data from

Comment: Yes, its same format for every line except i havent put spaces in between each after I had split them of the delimiters

Comment: Can you tell me the format, please? Perhaps just provide a sample date/time value from the file? I can't write code to parse the date without knowing the format.

Comment: The date time in the file is 1/1/2018 but I need that to stay the same. In the file it had semicolons separating the date from the precipitation and high temp and low temp such as this 1/1/2018;0;20;10. I was able to cut that out though

Comment: Is that day/month/year or month/day/year?

Comment: That is month/day/year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your model to use `DateTime` rather than `string` for the date:

```
struct Weather
{
    public DateTime date;
    public string precipitation;
    public string highTemp;
    public string lowTemp;
}
```

Change your read code like this:

```
string[] tokens = info.Split(delimiter);

// try to parse the date
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(tokens[0], "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var date))
{
    MessageBox.Show($"The file contains an invalid date: tokens[0].");
    return;
}
// store the values into the structure weather variables
weather.date = date;
weather.precipitation = tokens[1];
weather.highTemp = tokens[2];
weather.lowTemp = tokens[3];
// add to the list
weatherList.Add(weather);
```

And finally, change your code in dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged to be like this:

```
foreach(Weather weather in weatherList.Where(w => w.date.Date == dateTime.Date))
{
    string dateAsString = weather.date.ToString("M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    listBox1.Items.Add(dateAsString + weather.highTemp + weather.lowTemp);
}
```

[Documentation for TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__):

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format, culture-specific format information, and style. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly. The method returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

[Documentation for DateTime's ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_):

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent string representation using the specified format and culture-specific format information.

I recommend also reading Microsoft's [C# coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) and following them to some degree, since following a common development style makes it easier for other people to read and maintain your code.

P.S. Note that you're calling `fileData()` every time your datepicker value changes, and `fileData()` doesn't clear the list before filling it. You'll end up with duplicate values like this. I'd recommend either clearing the list before filling it, or moving the call to `fileData()` to the form load event.

Comment: Lol I'm sorry but you're using things that I have never seen before. I tried it and I'm guessing I need to include a library for CultureInfo

Comment: @Fitzgerald Ah you need to add `using System.Globalization;` at the top of your code file for that. Note that if you right-click `CultureInfo`, there should be an option in the refactor menu to include its using (I assume you're using Visual Studio).

Comment: We're parsing the date because your date as it's read from the file is a `string` (text), whereas we want it as the C# `DateTime` type. To make the conversion we need to interpret the date in its M/d/yyyy format (e.g. 1/31/2018, etc.) which is what we use `TryParseExtract` for. The `.ToString("M/d/yyyy"...` method converts a `DateTime` to a `string` value again for displaying to the user.

Comment: Recommend to PascalCase the public members of the struct- might as well get em started on proper C# conventions early!

Comment: @CaiusJard Good point. I've added a link to Microsoft's coding conventions document. :)

Comment: @Fitzgerald When llama says "refactor menu" they mean something like "point to/click on the word with the wiggly red line under it and when the  appears near the word or in the margin, click on it and choose the option to fix it up by "add "using System.Globalization"" or similar wording. There is also another option to "fully qualify" which will work but tends to make the code a bit more messy- I only do it if I know I'll only do it once in a file, or if three is a naming clash that prevents using `using`

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger to find out why it works. This is essentially the sensible notion of taking text data and presenting it using data types for what it *is* (a date time) rather than as text, which is harder to work with (you can't subtract 10 days off a string that merely happens to look like a date time)

Comment: Brilliant, it worked. And thank you for the little bit of clarification. I'll need to look more into this in the future.